# Wait for ReBus event handler

Tags: c#, messaging, rebus

Is there any mechanizm in Rebus which allows to specify action to invoke after speficic handler handles a message? In other words, callback?

I register hansler like this:

```
serviceCollection.AutoRegisterHandlersFromAssemblyOf<Handler1>()
serviceCollection.AddRebus(....);
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildProvider();
serviceProvider.UseRebus();




public class Handler1 : IHandleMessages<Message1>
{
   public Task Handle(Message1 message)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"Handler1 received : {message}");
       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

now, I would like to do something like this:

```
serviceProvider.GetService<IBus>(); //or whatever needed

//wait 2000ms until Handler1 handles Message1 with specific ID
await bus.WaitUntilHandled<Handler1, Message1>(
    message => message.Id = id, 
    new TaskCancellationSource(2000));
```

Comment: Probably you need this https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.Async?

Comment: No, I don't need reply from evenhandlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebus' built-in extension mechanism (for [the message pipelines](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Extensibility#pipelines)) lets you do almost anything you want to do, but in your case I think it would be easier to pull in [Rebus.Events](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.Events) and do something like this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Events(e =>
    {
        e.AfterMessageHandled += (bus, headers, message, context, args) =>
        {
            // do your thing in here
        };        
    });
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. AfterMessageHandler waits until the handler completes or it is fired as soon as the message is delivered to handler? 2. If I have server that produces events, and client that handles the events, where this event occurs?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question :) are you asking for a callback _on the sender's side_ to be called when the handler _on the receiver's side_ has finished executing?

Comment: No. I'm asking for callback on handler side.

Comment: Ok then: 1: `AfterMessageHandled` is fired when the message has been properly handled, potentially including an exception caught when handling it in the `args` passed to it. 2: The endpoint that handles the message raises this event.

Comment: One more urelated question: Is is possible to check on both, sender's and handler's side, whether there is specific event waiting to be handled by specific handler?

Comment: Very specific answer: no 

Comment: Neither on handler side only? I guess there's some storage or queue for events waiting to be handled, isn't it?

Comment: All commands and events are eventually delivered to a queue, from which the consumer receives them. This means that events waiting to be handled are simply sitting there, interleaved with all other messages to be received.

Comment: So by checking the event in the queue I actually check that there is an event waiting to be handled, don't I?

Comment: oh yeah sure, sorry – for some reason I assumed you wanted to be able to do it with code somehow, but yes definitely! If you have a queue inspection tool, you can go and see everything waiting to be handled. Rebus even comes with its own crude MSMQ inspector, Rebus Snoop: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Snoop

Comment: Yeah, I'm still hoping that there is some abtract ReBus API to inspect the queue

Comment: AfterMessageHandled is fired once all eventhandlers are invoked, but I would like to wait for specific eventhandler only. Is that possible?

Comment: Rebus invokes matching handlers in its [DispatchIncomingMessageStep](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Pipeline/Receive/DispatchIncomingMessageStep.cs). If you want to do something _between_ invoking some of the handlers, you probably need to replace this step with your own dispatcher that then enabled you to install a callback and have it invoked at just the right time.

Comment: Is it possible to replace HandlerInvoker with my own implementation? It seems to be ideal place for handler callback

Comment: Yes, definitely - you could add a step to the incoming messages pipeline that replaces `HandlerInvokers` (a list of `HandlerInvoker` instances) with your own, where each handler invoker then is your own class derived from `HandlerInvoker`. Your class would then implement the necessary logic to delegate all calls to its wrapped `HandlerInvoker`, and then make necessary callbacks

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate your great support. Second, have you ever considered making more methods protected virtual instead of private? I don't feel  very confident replacing  `DispatchIncomingMessageStep` or  `ActivateHandlersStep` entirely. e.g method `GetHandlerInvokers` could be virtual. I guess there is a lot more extension points where this could be useful

Comment: @Liero Well... I guess you are right :) but no, I didn't really consider that. The places you mention are definitely places where that could be done, but it's also kind of tricky, because it adds to the size of the public API surface to be considered when evaluating whether a change is breaking. It's something I will try and keep in mind though :)